# MailCorpus using pip

Tags: python

I have python 3.7.4 and want to install MailCorpus using pip.

I use this but I receive error:

```
>pip install MailCorpus
Collecting MailCorpus
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MailCorpus (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MailCorpus
```

Any problem with version?

Comment: It looks like there is no MailCorpus package on the PyPI (https://pypi.org/search/?q=mailcorpus). What are you trying to install exactly?

Comment: What is mailcorpus? I can't find any mention of it online.

Comment: @Corsaka it is from here https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD

Comment: That site tells you how to install it, if you scroll down to the part called "Installation".